# InterativeSideMenu Library issue for IOS Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project with one navigation controller and I am also making use of the InteractiveSideMenu library which can be found here : https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu. The main issue is, when I embed the rootview controller, based on the specification of the library, I have to create a class the calls the delegate to show the side menu for the root view controller like so:
    class NavigationViewController: UINavigationController, SideMenuItemContent {
}

This will enable to Sidemenu before the main view controller is declared in another class under UIViewController like this
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{}

The main issue here is, I have a navbar button that I call to display the side menu using this IBAction:

```
@IBAction func sideMenuDisplay(_ sender: Any) {
    if let navigationViewController = self.navigationController as? SideMenuItemContent {
        navigationViewController.showSideMenu()
    }
}
```

But it appears the if statement resolves to false and hence, the sidemenu is not triggered on this IBaction. I am very new to IOS and finding it really difficult wrapping my head around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, you need to set the class of your navigation controller to be your custom 'Navigation View Controller.'

That is found on the right-hand side under the 'Identity Inspector'

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked that, but even after adding this, the if statement is still false and the button doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You must do the same for the UIViewController. It works for me when I test it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the same class for the UIViewController as recommended but then I receive an error. Just to clarify, do you mean to set the custom "navigation view controller" for the UIView controller as well? When I do this I get the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: No. I mean you need to set the custom class of your UIViewController to be the ViewController class you created. From your code, it looks like the class name is 'ViewController,' so set that to your UIViewController class in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also have a issue with the table view when it has multiple sections, is this some issue you have faced before? I am not able to identify the section in the table view

Comment: any answer on this ?

Comment: @AnandChandra  Do you have working solution for it. I'm trying as you mentioned above but its not opening up menu when I have pushed another view controller.